# Javascript Underscore how to share identical callbacks

Tags: javascript, closures, underscore.js

Is it possible to share identical callbacks? how would I pass the _id as a second parameter to the callback?

e.g.

```
function getEntry(_id) {

    if (_id === undefined) {
        return false;
    }
    return _(this.scope[this.key]).find(function(entry) {
        return entry._id === _id;
    });
}

function getEntryIndex(_id) {
    if (_id === undefined) {
        return false;
    }
    return _(this.scope[this.key]).findIndex(function(entry) {
        return entry._id === _id;
    });
}
```

What I would like to do is create one callback -e.g predicate- for both findIndex and find as they are doing the same task, but how to pass _id to predicate?

```
  function predicate(entry, _id) {
      return entry._id === _id;
  }

  function getEntry(_id) {

      if (_id === undefined) {
          return false;
      }
      return _(this.scope[this.key]).find(predicate);
  }

  function getEntryIndex(_id) {
      if (_id === undefined) {
          return false;
      }
      return _(this.scope[this.key]).findIndex(predicate);
  }
```

Comment: I think you have been down-voted due to lack of information. I've read your question and your code over a couple times, but it is still very unclear to me what you are really asking for help on. Some more information might help you get a solid answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend restructuring your `predicate` function, like this

```
function predicate(_id, entry) {
    return entry._id === _id;
}
```

And then bind the value of `_id` when you are passing it to `find` or `findIndex` like this

```
return _(this.scope[this.key]).find(_.partial(predicate, _id)).value();
....
return _(this.scope[this.key]).findIndex(_.partial(predicate, _id)).value();
```

Note the [`.value()`](http://underscorejs.org/#value) call at the end. That will give the actual value returned.

---

In fact, you can refactor your code to use only one `getEntry` function, like this

```
function predicate(_id, entry) {
    return entry._id === _id;
}

function getEntry(func, _id) {
    if (_id === undefined) {
        return false;
    }
    return _[func](this.scope[this.key], _.partial(predicate, _id));
}

getEntry('find', 1);
getEntry('findIndex', 1);
```

Here, we choose the function to be invoked with a parameter, `func` and then create a new function with [`_.partial`](http://underscorejs.org/#partial) which applies the `_id` parameter to `predicate` function.